# VersionOne SDK not working with VS2019 and Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, versionone

I want to create a mobile app for connecting to Collabnet VersionOne (REST API). VersionOne has an SDK, but it's only .Net Framework 4.5.1 (Nuget: VersionOne.SDK.APIClient) and Visual Studio 2013 that is supported.

I'm trying to install the NuGet package in Visual Studio 2019, but it fails, e.g, on only supporting .Net v451 - is this never doing to work? Or should I put some effort into it, to try it out?

Anyone working with VersionOne SDK and mobile apps?

Comment: You are trying to install the package into what kind of project? I would ask the author to update the SDK to .NET Standard to cover more target frameworks. Looking at their code, it doesn't seem like anything is preventing them from migrating to .NET Standard.

Comment: It might not be a big thing if you know what you are doing, but I'm completely new to .Net so I wouldn't know where to start - but I will reach out to the author.

Answer (score -1):

You could temporarily make it work by

1. Opening your Core project settings
2. Go to general, select .NET Portable and change the settings so it targets the framework supported by that library, by changing the PCL profile
   [image: Core project options in Visual Studio]

You can also help them to migrate to the latest .NetStandard

Comment: I don't know whether this is possible. I'm only able to select .Net Core versions and not 451, even though it should be installed. Maybe it's not possible for android/xamarin development, which is what I'm doing?